# Is this the correct phrase: העול של תורה

Tags: midrash, derabanan

The Yoke of the Torah

Please adjust so I have the phrasing/prepositions correct. (And any source references welcome!)

Comment: Pirkei Avot 3:5 has it as עול תורה

Answer (score 1):

Technically, "**The** Yoke of **the** Torah" would be: **ה**עול של **ה**תורה. Since you have two definite articles in the English, you would want two in the Hebrew. Your phrase in Hebrew would be "The Yoke of Torah." Either usage is correct.

You can also find "עולה של תורה"/"The Torah's Yoke". See [these](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94&tab=text&tvar=0&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) examples.

Comment: Or עול התורה (using semikhut)